# Codeignite - Porque minha rota não funciona?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho a  seguinte rota em routes.php:

```
$route['xxxxx/(:any)'] = 'Order/index/$1';
```

E o seguinte index no controller Order:

```
public function index(){
    switch( $this->uri->segment(2)){
      case $this->step2:
        $this->motivation();
      break;
      case $this->step3:
        $this->about();
      break;
      case $this->status:
        $this->status();
      break;
      case 'post':
        $this->post();
      break;
      case 'teste':
        $this->teste();
      break;
      default:
        $this->register();
      break;
    }
  }
```

Porem quando eu tento entrar nessa rota digitando **localhost/xxxxx** por exemplo, ela me retorna erro **404 Page Not Found**.

Comment: E se acessar `localhost/xxxxx/teste`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ai funciona

Comment: Aparentemente só funciona se eu passo um segundo segmento

Comment: E `localhost/xxxxx/`, com a barra no final?

Comment: Com a barra no final n funciona tambem, mesma coisa

Comment: Como está a função? desse controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quiser um parâmetro opcional deve então criar duas configurações de rota, o `Framework` não possui outra forma (*é limitado nesse aspecto*), então faça:

***Exemplo:***

```
$route['xxxxx'] = 'Order/index';
$route['xxxxx/(:any)'] = 'Order/index/$1';
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#uri-routing)</sub>

Também vale lembrar para que isso funcione sem problemas o parâmetro que é opcional deve ter algum valor padrão, exemplo:

```
class Order extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($id = null)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

no caso exemplo as duas rotas funcionam para essa método!

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado, fiz um if no index para tratar no caso do segundo segmento não existir